# Storing Data to Map

Tags: c++

I have created a map with wstring as key on a struct for data but when i tried to run iterator for showing data of the map, it skips the first data that i added. Here is the code.

```
typedef struct
{
public:
wstring source;
wstring synthetic;
int operation;
int divisor;
}SSParams;

map<wstring, SSParams>SSParameters;

for(int x=0;x<sizeofdata;x++)
{
 SSParameters[srcsymbol[x]].source = srcsymbol[x];
 SSParameters[srcsymbol[x]].synthetic = synsymbol[x];
 SSParameters[srcsymbol[x]].operation = operation[x];
 SSParameters[srcsymbol[x]].divisor = divisor[x];
 m_api->LoggerOut(Log, L"Source: %s Synth: %s, Operation: %d, Value: %d, Total: %d", SSParameters[srcsymbol].source, SSParameters[srcsymbol].synthetic, SSParameters[srcsymbol].operation, SSParameters[srcsymbol].divisor,SSParameters.size());
}

map<wstring, SSParams>::iterator iter;
for (iter = SSParameters.begin(); iter != SSParameters.end(); ++iter)
{
    m_api->LoggerOut(Log, L"Data Source: %s, Synth: %s, Operation: %d, Divisor: %d", iter->second.source, iter->second.synthetic, iter->second.operation, iter->second.divisor);
}
```

Output (Insertion loop):

```
Source: HCBC Synth: HCBCx, Operation:1, Value: 100, Total: 1
Source: HCBC Synth: HCBCv, Operation:1, Value: 100, Total: 1
```

Output (Iterator loop):

```
Data Source: HCBC Synth: HCBCv, Operation:1, Value: 100
```

As you can see, i added values as well as the key to the map using for loop and the log shows that i added the data successfully but when i try to run the iterator, i shows the data but skip the first one.

Comment: Try reading this, it really helps in such cases: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should also provide an example input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I think the problem only added one element to the map since the variable "srcsymbol" seems to be unchanged

Comment: check `SSParameters.size()` first.

Comment: SSParameters.size always returns 1 which means the data is added but after the second loop it returns 1 again it is like its overwriting the first data

Comment: @Raven Then your  `srcsymbol[x]` is always the same, regardless of x value. Map adds unique keys only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test that keys that are inserted are unique using:

```
for(int x=0;x<sizeofdata;x++)
{
    assert(SSParameters.count(srcsymbol[x])==0);
    SSParameters[srcsymbol[x]].source = srcsymbol[x];
```

requires `<cassert>`

Comment: Of course they should. A map "maps" unique keys to values. If keys are not unique you'll just overwrite existing entries. If that's not the behaviour you want then you should use a different container.

Comment: yes, keys in a `map` are always unique, if you reuse a key, the old value associated with that key will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Since `srcsymbol` does not change in the loop you are just adding one element and then continuously overwriting its contents. End result; the map holds only a single element.

Comment: sorry for that but every loop the srcsymbol has different value

Comment: Maybe now that you changed it to `srcsymbol[x]`. Before, it did not.

Comment: @Raven maybe you should also print srcsymbol[x] to make sure that they have different value

Answer (score 0):

From the output of insert loop, srcsymbol[x] always equal to HCBC. Hence the program only added one element to the map.